# The constructor being called isn't a const constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am brand new to flutter and programming in general -so please bear with me-, so I am taking a course on udemy and I stumbled with this error  (The constructor being called isn't a const constructor)
This is the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar:AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Text('This is my default text'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its help to you. remove `const` keyword

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Text('This is my default text'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Your result screen-> [image]